# Kensei using Deflect Missile through Sentinel

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, ranged-attack

I've got a blindsense defensive Kensei monk who specializes in thrown weapons, and he has deflect missiles and the Sentinel feat. If someone is firing a ranged weapon at his teammates, can he strike said projectiles out of the air with his own throwing blades?

And/or what additional abilities would be required to do this?

Comment: I once heard someone suggest a cursed shield of arrow catching to get more use out of their Deflect Missiles. I'd still like to see someone try that in a real game some time.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 11):

## RAW, no

Deflect Missiles works on ranged attacks targeted at you. The Sentinel feat does absolutely nothing to change that. You seem to be misreading the following part from Sentinel:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you makes an attack against a target other than you (and that target doesn’t have this feat), you can use your reaction to make a melee weapon attack against the attacking creature.

A ranged weapon's ammunition hitting somebody is not "a creature attacking somebody", so nothing in the rules will allow you to attack the ammunition.

However, if a character with a ranged weapon attacks somebody other than you, and you are standing next to them, you will get to use your reaction to attack them. (But their attack will still go through, you do not stop it.)

Using Deflect Missile to protect somebody else sounds like a great, fun way to flavor the ability more, but you're entirely in homebrew territory, it is not something supported by the rules.